# Jenkins Flutter permission denied

Tags: flutter, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins pipeline on a Flutter project, I've configured the flutter SDK inside an EC2 instance, however, I get the following error:
[image]

I don't know what the error could possibly be about, is it some permission that has to be added inside the Github account, or is some kind of permission that needs to be added inside the **Jenkins** file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins probably does not have all the required permissions to execute flutter commands. The easiest fix would probably be to change ownership of the flutter installation directory to Jenkins user.

This can be achieved with:

```
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /opt/flutter/
```

Please adjust the path of flutter installation if needed.